# Заливка выделенных объектов на сцене

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня на сцене (QGraphicsScene) находится несколько прямоугольников (QGraphicsRectItem). Я их выделяю (установил соответствующий флаг у QGraphicsView), а как мне изменить цвет выделенных объектов (я знаю, как получить указатели на выделенные объекты, но как залить не знаю) или по нажатию кнопки или по нажатию на выделенную область (цвет пока-что не важен, я хотел бы понять процесс залития выделенной области)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem`, наследником коего является ваш `QGraphicsRectItem`, есть свойство `brush` то есть кисть. Вот она то и используется для закраски объекта. Установить кисть можно с помощью метода  [QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem::setBrush](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractgraphicsshapeitem.html#setBrush).

Для получения выделеных объектов можно использовать метод `QGraphicsScene::selectedItems` который возвращает список выделенных объектов. Для того чтобы обрабатывать события о том, что произошло выделение можно использовать сигнал `QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged`

В сумме получается примерно так:

```
void SceneManager::OnConnectionChanged()
{
     for(auto item : Scene.selectedItems())
     {
         item->setBrush(SelectedBrush);
     }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я это в принципе знаю, у меня основная проблема в том, что я не знаю, как залить именно выделенную область (то есть выделенные элементы, которые способны принимать выделение)